# How to Split up a string that was read from a file

Tags: python, list, split

I'm having problems splitting up this list in python. What I want it to do is split the list but keep Passwords linked to Username.

```
Users = []
NewUser = input("Enter the new Users Username: ")
UserPass = input("Enter the new Users Password: ")
Users.append([NewUser, UserPass])
Pfile = open('Passwords','r')
print(Pfile.read())
CurrentUsers = Pfile.read()
Pfile.close
Pfile = open('Passwords','w')
OldUsers = []
OldUsers = CurrentUsers.split()
print(OldUsers)
Users.append(OldUsers)
print(Users)
```

The problem I get is that the string is completely destroyed rather than split at the last three prints I get:

```
[['Dan', 'Span'], ['Tim', 'Can']]  - previous data already stored
['']  - the split values
[['Tin', 'im'], ['']] - the new values added to my previous list
```

I think it might be a typo or an incorrect way of splitting the list

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using a file not a DB? I suggest using a DB (such as MySQL) with a proper password hashing scheme (don't roll your own) for this.

Comment: Splitting the list? You mean the string? because split() is a str-method

Comment: You are also not closing the file `Pfile.close <- no parens`, you should use `with` to open your files and you won't have to close them yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You read() twice from the file. First store the read value into a variable, then print that variable.

Once you read() all data from an opened input stream, that stream is "exhausted" and reading again from it does not produce any additional data (I.e., the file isn't simply "read again".) That's why you are seeing the empty string in your results.

Comment: You may want to explain that calling `read` moves the pointer to the end of the file, so calling `read` again reads from the end of the file.  This can be fixed by doing as you suggest and storing that value in a variable and using it, or by calling `seek(0)` on the open file before reading again.

Comment: I agree that is another possibility. Even simpler would be to just open() another IO stream on the file again. But given those are clearly less efficient solutions and as I assume OP is just learning Python or even programming, it was best to leave it there.